# Open Layers Features move when zooming out

Tags: javascript, openlayers

EDIT: I changed the center of the map by user-input before but changed this for testing. Using a fixed center for my map, everything is fine. Question now is: why?

I am looping through a JSON with some features, extracting the coordinates for each feature, and add them to a map.
So far everything is working fine, but I just noticed that the features or better the icons are moving when I am zooming out/in or moe left/right.
The feature location should still be true since I am able to hover over the map and show an overlay (as intended).

I have no idea why the logos would behave like this, maybe someone can help me. Here is my code for one of the layers:

```
///////////////
// Forst
var Forststyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'images/tree.png'
})
});
var Forstsource = new ol.source.Vector();
$.getJSON('config/Forst.json', function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(key, val){
     var newMarker = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point([this.long, this.lat]),
            pointAttributes: {            
                'Name': this.name, 
                'Strasse':this.Straße,
            }        
    });
    Forstsource.addFeature(newMarker);
    });
});
var Forst = new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: "Forst",
        visible: false,
        zIndex: 5,
        style: Forststyle,
        source: Forstsource});
```

I am adding the Forst-Layer to the layers of my map.

I thought my projection/view definition might be helpful.

```
var projection25832 = new ol.proj.Projection({
code: 'EPSG:25832',
    // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
    // projection's validity extent can be found at https://epsg.io/.
extent: [-1877994.66, 3932281.56, 836715.13, 9440581.95],
units: 'm'
});
```

I am adding my whole map-call. center and zoom get defined by user-input.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers:[          
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'OSM (grau)',
            visible: true,
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                url: 'https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?',
                    params: {
                        'LAYERS': "OSM-WMS",
                        'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                        'FORMAT': 'image/png',
                        'TILED': false
                         }
            })
            }),
            Schaefer,
            KMR,
            GaLaBauSA, 
            GaLaBauBBG,
            Forst,
            Lohnunternehmen
            ],   
    view: new ol.View({
            projection: projection25832,
            center: center,
            zoom: zoom
        })
});
```

I am adding some images, view1 and view2 are only changed by scrolling left/right, view3 is zoomed in.

[image: View1]

[image: view2]

[image: view3]

[image: tree.png]

Some more edits:
As stated above, when I am using a fixed center everything is working as intended. However, changing it depending on User Input is not working.

```
var D = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(){
       var Coords = D.responseJSON.results[0].locations[0].latLng;
       var utm = "+proj=utm +zone=32";
       var new_center = [proj4("WGS84",utm,[Coords.lng, Coords.lat])[0],proj4("WGS84",utm,[Coords.lng, Coords.lat])[1]];
       console.log(new_center);
       CreateMap([new_center[0], new_center[1]],zoom);
       $("#Hintergrund").hide();
       });
       }
```

My CreateMap function is taking the coordinates of the center and the zoom, the url is a WEB-API (mapquest) that turns input into coordinates. If I pass e.g. my home-zip-code I get the coordinates that are used as my fixed center in the log, so there should not be a problem with the coordinates right?

Comment: Can you add the `tree.png` icon?

Comment: The basemap looks distorted, so it is likely not in the default 3857 projection. What projection are you using? The forest points do not contain projection information.

Comment: I am using EPSG:25832, the coordinates of the point are stored in this projection. I will check how to add the projection to the points.
I used esentially the same code as on https://forestwatch.lup-umwelt.de/app_development/ for the Layers Fotos/Drohnenbilder where everything is working fine. Only difference seems to be the basemap gray/not gray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image moving on zoom, because it automatically scales so the size would be readable regarding the zoom level (It doesn't stick to the map) You would need to anchor the center of the image elsewhere.

To anchor the center image you must play around with offsets.
You can, play with offsets and image size itself with openlayers style class. I dont know which version you are using, so you most likely will have to read about it in the documentation or some other examples, but hare is one.

```
new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0, 0],
            anchorXUnits: "pixels",
            anchorYUnits: "pixels",
            offset: [0,0],
            offsetOrigin: 'bottom-left',
            rotation: 0,
            src: 'images/tree.png'
        }))
    });
```

*Setting anchor to 0,0 will be top left if Im not mistaken, you most likely will have to set it to 0, {Half width}*

Basically, when you scroll and zoom, OpenLayers adjusts your image scaling from its center point, so in theory it will move if the center point isnt for example at the bottom.
If that doesn't help, see if you have correct projections.
And if that doesn't help, try creating "Markers" instead of points, I don't recall but one of them has way more control flow going.

I imagined it moved by tiny bit, seems like it drastically moves. Might be projections fault. Try to use  `projection: 'EPSG:4326'` if your coordinates are in different one, you can convert it with

```
.transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"))
```

I noticed you create projection manualy, not sure if thats the best approach. Check out this one.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/epsg-4326.html
Its using 4326. It is always better to use openlayers projection and if you have coordinates built differently, transform them to your needed ones.

To debug this, you can try to draw a linestring on a map (WKT/Polyline) if that changes on zoom, your problem is definitely in projections, if not, then it might be something else.

I was working with openlayers recently as well. And ran into the same problem, which I made by add

```
    style.graphicXOffset= 15;
    style.graphicYOffset= 28;
```

Set these to 0, should help.

Comment: I tried your solution but it did not work :( I will check the Markers part though. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Adding images would help aswell @Felix

Comment: I added some images :)

Comment: I will try if it works with changed coordinates! If you look at (https://forestwatch.lup-umwelt.de/app_development/) and open the layers on the left and select Fotos, you will see what I want to do. And I am using the same code.

Comment: Yeh, but this map might be using correct coordinate system, if you are using literally same codde, the only thing is different - coordinates. I expect it uses a popup to display images and info. But for the points itself, simple point or marker should be enough. Play arround with your projections, they can be pain in the ass. Try to set different projection for your map (Use default openlayers integrated one) even the wrong ones, see how it effects it. And keep playing with it, will give you more debugging options.

Comment: I am legit using the same code. Before I changed the center of the map in the view option depending on some user input, but I have to change this somehow.

Comment: Well, like I mentioned, then the only thing thats float of value is the coordinates, might be using different projections, or converting from wrong projection all togethor

Comment: @Felix acidentaly made the same mess, try set them to 0